# EPPLUS generated xlsx files needs recover on open

Tags: epplus

I'm using EPPLUS to generate reports and that works fine.

In case I assign valid excel formula in some cells formula property, formulas are rejected, I'm getting warnings: "We found a problem with some content in..." and "Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part".

Formula looks like:"=IF(Worksheet1!C9-Calculation!$B$1=0;24;IF(Worksheet1!C9-Calculation!$B$1<0;Worksheet1!C9-Calculation!$B$1+24;Worksheet1!C9-Calculation!$B$1))" and it works if I paste it directly to excel.

My formula related code looks like:

```
ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet1");
excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Calculation");
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Worksheet1"];
ExcelWorksheet worksheet2 = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Calculation"];

for (int c = 1; c <= monthcnt; c++)
{
    NumColumns cellAddr = (NumColumns)c;

    string addr1 = string.Format("Worksheet1!{0}{1}", cellAddr.ToString(), 8);
    worksheet2.Cells[addr1].Formula = string.Format("={0}-Calculation!$B$1", addr1);
    string addr2 = string.Format("Worksheet1!{0}{1}", cellAddr.ToString(), 9);
    worksheet2.Cells[addr2].Formula = string.Format("=IF({0}-Calculation!$B$1=0;24;IF({1}-Calculation!$B$1<0;{2}-Calculation!$B$1+24;{3}-Calculation!$B$1))", addr2, addr2, addr2, addr2);
}
```

Does anybody knows what causes this?
Thanks in advance,
Siniša

Comment: Should post your code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: There's plenty of code:

Comment: Are you calling `excel.Dispose()` somewhere further down to properly close the object?

Comment: Of course, cause I'm instantiating ExcelPackage without using statement. Btw, I found a problem; my formula allways substracting content of 9-th cell in C column no matter if there's a content. Excel itself can handle that, but Epplus has problem in  that case. Thnx :)